# Validation POST & GET methods in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using annotation to set my routes and method types. Is there a way to only allow certain types of post data. Currently I'm doing the following:

```
/**
 * @Route("/myurl", requirements={"varID" = "\d+"} )
 * @Method({"POST"})
 * @Template()
 */
```

But if a varID gets submitted with a string value then it goes through anyway... I'm guessing due partly to there being no {varID} in the route? Is there a way to validate POST data like this in Symfony?

Answer (score 0):

Change annotation into this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/myurl/{varID}", requirements={"varID" = "\d+"} )
 * @Method({"POST"})
 * @Template()
 */
```

You must tell symfony wich part of url is yours varID variable to allow engine to check datatype. Than you get an exception:

```
 No route found for "GET /myurl/somestring"
 404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException
 1 linked Exception:
```

Comment: But wouldn't that require a URL like "/myurl/6767" for example? If I'm putting the varID in the URL then that removes the need for a POST method anyway, right? ..or am I missing something?

Comment: you are missing :)
render your form tag like this:
<form action="{{ path('route_name_to_action', {'varID': passedVar}) }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST" " role="form">
Than you get same GET/POST requests

Comment: Or user helper function:
`{{ form_start(form, {'method': 'POST', 'action': path('route_name_to_action', {'varID': passedVar}) }) }}`

Comment: but the form is already being sent with POST data correctly. The problem is receiving this POST data... as it states in the question.

Comment: if it was send correctly you wouldnt ask this question.
run in terminal `php app/console router:debug` you will see that you have 1 route to Action with NO params - so no control about param datatype. If you use it right, build route with param and send it EVERY time, then your app will work fine. 
Now what happens when you pass no param with GET request? What object do you put to the form? Your routing and method allow that.

Comment: I'm not asking about sending correctly... I'm asking about receiving POST data and validating it like I would if the variable was sent via the URL. I know my code does not work currently, I'm trying to find out if what I'm asking is possible. For now... just take it that the POST data I'm sending is correct, that I don't want my variables in the URL, and that i want to validate my data via `requires=` annotation. I appreciate your answers but I feel something's getting lost in translation. Please post code examples if you think this is incorrect?

Comment: Ok, if you want to send varID as a param via POST request just add <input name=varID"... to your form. If you dont want to show this field make it [hidden](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/hidden.html)

You can validate all form variables using [validation servce](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html)
How to enable that and how to configure that you can find [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#configuration)

Comment: Oh my, I give up. I'm sure you're trying to help but I fear you can't currently understand what I'm asking.

Comment: Ok, try to ask one more time. You dont want to validate datatype of variable passed to function, you dont want to validate datatype inside a function, after being send. You want to validate before send? or send form data to different function determine of variables datatype? I dont see any other options :)

Comment: I want to send POST variables from outside of my controller to my controller, and validate them the way I would if they were GET variables I.E: using `requirements={"varID" = "\d+"}` to ensure my varID (sent from a POST action form) is a number only, otherwise the page is not found.